# Difference between get() and by lazy

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

Having a room Dao as below,

```
@Dao
public abstract class AccountDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Account LIMIT 0,1")
    public abstract Account readAccount();
}
```

is there any differences between `get()` and `by lazy` in the sample below?

```
open val account: LiveData<Account>
        get() = accountDao.readAccount()
```

```
open val account: LiveData<Account> by lazy { accountDao.readAccount() }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The difference is in how many times the function body (`accountDao.readAccount()`) will be executed.

The `lazy` delegate will execute the lambda one single time the first time it is accessed and remember the result. If it is called again, that cached result is returned.

On the other hand, defining the getter (`get()`) will execute the function body every time, returning a new result every time.

For example, let's suppose we have a class called `Foo` with both a getter and a lazy value:

```
class Foo {
    val getterVal: String
        get() = System.nanoTime().toString()

    val lazyVal: String by lazy { System.nanoTime().toString() }
}
```

And then use it:

```
fun main() {
    with(Foo()) {
        repeat(2) {
            println("Getter: $getterVal")
            println("Lazy:   $lazyVal")
        }
    }
}
```

For me, this prints:

```
Getter: 1288398235509938
Lazy:   1288398235835179
Getter: 1288398235900254
Lazy:   1288398235835179
```

And we can see that the getter returns a newly calculated value each time, and the lazy version returns the same cached value.

Comment: I'm presuming since it's `LiveData`, a single execution of `accountDao.readAccount()` should be sufficient?

Comment: it depends if you'd want an updated value for every call or a cached return

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Todd's answer:

Yes, there is a difference for `LiveData` objects as well. Every call of `accountDao.readAccount()` will result in a *different* `LiveData` object. And it does matter, despite the fact that all of the returned `LiveData` will get updated on every change in the `Account` entity. Let me explain on these examples:

- `by lazy`

As Todd mentioned, the block inside the `lazy` delegate will be executed once, at the first time that the `account` property is accessed, the result will be cached and returned on every next access. So in this case a single one `LiveData<Account>` object is created. The bytecode generated by Kotlin to achieve this is equivalent to this in Java:

```java
public class Activity {

    private Lazy account$delegate

    public LiveData<Account> getAccount() {
        return account$delegate.getValue();
    }
}
```

- `get()`

By creating a custom `account` property's getter and calling `accountDao.readAccount()` inside, you will end up with different `LiveData<Account>` objects on every access of the `account` property. Once more, bytecode generated for this case in Kotlin in Java is more or less this:

```java
public class Activity {

    public LiveData<Account> getAccount() {
        return accountDao.readAccount();
    }
}
```

---

So you can see, using a lazy property results in generating a backing field for this property, while using a custom getter creates a wrapper method for the `accountDao.readAccount()` call.

It's up to your needs which approach you should use. I'd say that if you have to obtain the `LiveData` only once, you should go with `get()`, because a backing field is needless in that case. However if you're going to access the `LiveData` in multiple places in your code, maybe a better approach would be to use `by lazy` and create it just once.